# VS Code Python import module doesnt work ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'words'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VSCode I try to import module but there is the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'words'
[screenshot from VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPBLe.png)

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Hey have you tried installing the words library. You can install words library by  using the following command `pip install words`.

Comment: Can you show the content from file `words.py`?

Comment: `words` is not a built-in module; you have to install it yourself.  Did you install it?

Comment: `words` is the OP own module.

Comment: The answer depends hugely on whether the module you're trying to import is installed with pip, or your own local module. And whether it is local or in a different subdirectory. And whether you use a virtual env. But either way this is a duplicate: see the existing [714 hits on *\[python\] vscode import*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+vscode+import+)  or [1115 hits on *\[python\] vs code import*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+vs+code+import+)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your script, `Untitled-1`, in the same directory as `words.py` file. The `import` statement looks for modules on `PATH` and in the current directory. Mind that currently your `words.py` are located deep in AppData directory, which is likely not the best place to stash project files.

Answer (score 1):

Put this two .py files into a folder, then open the folder in VS Code. You can import it successfully:

[image]

The folder **pycache** is generated after you run the file successfully.